# How can I Perform networking(save results in the database using volley) based on the result I got from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-volley, android-networking

I have an activity and a fragment. If I click a button then a fragment is called. Upon the result I got from the fragment I need some networking call to perform using volley. But I can't do any networking call from activity unless I call this within `onClick()` method.

I tried to perform networking from within `onClick()` of the fragment but that did not worked too.

How can i perform networking from the activity upon the result I got from the fragment? Do I must call from within `onClick()`?

[This is the fragment](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15260286/) 
[This is the Activity](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15260300/)

Comment: Please post some code of your attempts, simply saying that it does not work wont help

Comment: I have posted the code .

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use callback.

Create intefrace and declare method saveResult() in it.

```
 public interface YourInterface{
        void saveResult();
    }
```

After that  your Activity must  implement this interface and add your code for save result in database in saveResult method body

```
  public class YourActivity implements YourInterface{ 

       @override
       void saveResult(){
            //your code here
       }

}
```

And finnaly in your fragment call method when you whant or when your fragment is ready.You can call method with help of

```
callBack.saveResult();
```

You must override onAttach in your fragment and there must initialize your callback

```
YourInterface callback;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(activity instanceof YourInterface ) {
            callback = (YourInterface ) activity;
        }
    }
```

Try with other on click method in at your onCreate method

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mark_distribution);

        assign_buttton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.assign_marks);
        view_buttton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.view_marks);
        update_buttton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.update_marks);

        //Like this-->>>
        update_buttton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
           marks_type=(String)assigned_marks_type.getText().toString();
        marks=Integer.parseInt(assigned_marks.getText().toString().trim());
           callback.saveResult(marks_type,marks);
            }
        });
        //********************/

    Intent i=getIntent();
    course_title= i.getExtras().getString("COURSE_TITLE");

}
```

Hope to help you!

Comment: Thanx bro.....bt it didnot workdworked for me :(  :(     http://paste.ubuntu.com/15261542/  and http://paste.ubuntu.com/15261559/ her e are the codes.

Comment: and what did you want to happened at all ? when you click submit button to perform your method in your activity ?

Comment: yup..i want that when i click submit button in the fragment ..the interface implemented by the activity should be called .I found out that I can perform networking call only from within onClick() of that activity!

Comment: check my edit answer and try with this .. and if it doesnt work give me your error or what happaned at all :)

Comment: I solved it using another activity in place of that fragment before u gave me ur edited code. bt thnx bro :)